# Fragment android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to make 2 fragment, if I press the question then will replace the fragment question, and if the result of the fragment results. but of these codes are replaced only fp.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tersumbat);

        strings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Tersumbat);
        hasilstrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.HasilTersumbat);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        Tersumbat.FragmentPertanyaan fp = new Tersumbat.FragmentPertanyaan();
        Tersumbat.FragmentPertanyaan fh = new Tersumbat.Fragmenthasil();
        fp.setListener(this);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("pertanyaan", strings[0]);
        bundle.putString("hasil", strings[0]);
        bundle.putInt("posisi", 0);
        fp.setArguments(bundle);
        fh.setArguments(bundle);

        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fp).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fh).commit();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. I am not sure what your problem is here, would you mind adding some more information? like what is the `question` and  `fragment results`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
fragname fragname = new fragname();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putCharSequence(bundle_string, yourstring); 
                        fragname.setArguments(bundle); 
                        FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentlayout, fragname, fragname.getTag()).commit();
```

- Note:

if you're in a Activity and you're calling a new fragment, take out the I`getActivity().`, its only necessary whet you call a fragment from another fragment